# Multiple value / onChange values in a React form

Tags: reactjs

I must be missing something very simple, but I can't figure out how to deal with having 2 `value` / `onChange` to pass to my component.

I tried changing the names, and that gets rid of errors and renders the app, but of course `event.target.value` does not work as if I change the second `value` to, for example to `numval` or something. `event.target.numval` doesn't recognize anything is happening.

Thank you so much in advance! And if this has been asked before I apologize, but I couldn't find it... which makes me think I'm overlooking a very simple solution.

```
return (
 ...
<PersonForm
   onSubmit={addName}
   value={newName}
   onChange={handleName}
   value={newNumber}
   onChange={handleNumber} 
/>
)
```

Here is the original code that worked fine before I tried to put the component into its own file:

```
return (
...
<form onSubmit={addName}>
   <div>
      name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleName} />
   </div>
   <div>
      number: <input value={newNumber} onChange={handleNumber} />
   </div>
   <div>
      <button type="submit">add</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide a minimal, reproducible example on [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: I know you said minimal, hope this is what you meant! [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-clarke-2jvw8?file=/src/Filter.js) @AhmetEmreKılınç

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code sample is not clear but it seems you want to retrieve value from *event.target* object through event handler function triggered by *onChange* event on
an  element. And you want to call event handler function available in a parent component from a child component.

You can try the following:

```
const App () => {
    const [newNameValue, setName] = useState('');
    const [newNumberValue, setNumber] = useState('');
    const nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setName(event.target.value);
    };
    const numberChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setNumber(event.target.value);
    };
    const submitFormHandler = () => {
        your code on form submit
    };
    
    return (
        <PersonForm
            submitForm={submitFormHandler}
            newName={newNameValue}
            handleName={nameChangeHandler}
            newNumber={newNumberValue}
            handleNumber={numberChangeHandler} 
        />
    );
}

const PersonForm (props) => {
return (
        <form onSubmit={props.submitForm}>
   <div>
      name: <input value={props.newName} onChange={props.handleName} />
   </div>
   <div>
      number: <input value={props.newNumber} onChange={props.handleNumber} />
   </div>
   <div>
      <button type="submit">add</button>
   </div>
</form>
    );
}
```

*onChange* is a reserved attribute name which is available on few html elements
such as `<input>` and `<select>`. You should ideally not use it on other elements, like in your case custom html component `<PersonForm>`.
Since you're keeping *form* in separate component then you can trigger a function call received through attributes on *props* object.
You may call two different *onChange* event handler functions on two input elements.

I hope you got your answer, feel free to ask in case of any more doubts.

You may refer:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Hi, I saw your update on codesandbox, just call `onChange`  attribute on both <input> elements and trigger different attribute name on `props` object. And in `App.js` call event handler function on that attribute name. Follow my detailed code above.